# UIGestureRecognizer in CollectionView not being Recognized

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a CollectionView of cells that contain images. These images are being fed from a web service. I am trying to implement a UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown to allow the user to refresh the view. However, when I swipe down the View is handling it as a scroll as opposed to a UISwipeGesture. Is there a good way to different the actions?

Comment: Have you tried adding this method: `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}`

Comment: I have used that method... but it still does not fire the swipe down gesture.

Comment: I can only successfully have the Swipe Left / Right work correctly at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be working. I have been able to get it to work intermittently inside of the simulator. Based on my testing and other gesture issues, it appears that the Simulator has difficulty accurately translating the Gestures from a touchpad.